# How to remove space after last element in list

Tags: python, list

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for element in list:
    print(element, end=" ")
```

For this code, the output is: **1 2 3 4** .
But there is a space after the last element(4).How can I remove only that last space?I tried adding sep=" " before the end=" " but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to print everything, but the last element with space, then print the last without a space:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
    print(lst[i], end=" ")

print(lst[len(lst) - 1])
```

Comment: Please correct the OP on the naming, don't use `list` as variable name

Comment: This looks like the easiest solution for me. Tell me if I get it right.
We print all elements except the last one and in separate print, we print the last one.
Can we put a separate print in for loop or it must be outside of it?

Comment: I just name it for the example.Ty for advice anyway.

Comment: Exactly. The `print` for the last element is outside the loop. You could also get away with things like others suggested, like checking if the element is the last, but this adds unnecessary complexity and clutters the code.
If you like your code short you can even do it in 2 lines, first being the loop and the second printing using a ternary operator.

Comment: Sorry but this isn't Pythonic at all. Using `print(*lst)` or join is much more readable. There is no need to use two separate codes to do this simple task.

Answer (score 5):

You could just use `join` here:

```py
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
output = ' '.join([str(x) for x in values])
print(output)  # 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: We didn't learn that yet.To be honest I don't have any idea what join does.Is there some beginner-friendly solution for this problem?

Comment: @Kalaba That is very beginner friendly. What `join` does ? It joins the argument `','.join([1,2,3]) ==> '1,2,3'`

Answer (score 1):

This would also work.

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for element in lst:
    if element == lst[len(lst)-1]:
      print(element)
    else:
      print(element, end=" ")
```

Comment: Please correct the OP on the naming, don't use `list` as variable name

Comment: I was trying to match his code, but I have made the appropriate correction. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can print the first n-1 elements with space and then print the last element separately.

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in l[:-1]:
    print(i, end=" ")
print(l[-1], end="")
```

Comment: Please correct the OP on the naming, don't use `list` as variable name

Comment: Yep. But it works when the name is `list` too! Thanks for the tip @azro !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can print the list by converting it into a list and then use `join()`

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4] # Don't use keywords for naming variables (it is a bad practice)
my_list = [str(x) for x in my_list]
print(' '.join(my_list))
```

If you want a longer solution then

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4]
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    if i != len(my_list)-1:
        print(str(my_list[i]) + " ", end='')
    else:
        print(str(my_list[i]), end='')
```

Comment: Your first solution isn't going to work, because the items of the list are not strings. You can't use `join`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @SorousHBakhtiary, I have edited the solution

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is:

```
print(*lst)
```

`*` operator is for unpacking, it passes individual list items to the print function like `print(1, 2, 3, 4)`. `print` function use default `" "` space for the separator.

**note**: Internally `print` calls `__str__` method of the elements, I mean it convert it to the string.

Also don't forget to not using built-in names like `list`.

Comment: I just name it for example.Ty anyway.
So basically what * does is that it converts the list into a string.

Comment: @Kalaba No. It unpacks the iterables. List is an iterable so it unpacks it too. the `*` operator, pass the individual items of an iterable here list, to ke `print` function. `print` function itself calls the `__str__` method of the items in order to print them.

Comment: Your solution works for printing specifically, but it defeats the general problem. Say, the OP wants to print the `value+1`. How are you going to do that with a pointer?

Comment: @ValentinPopescu He was trying to print the elements of a list/iterable in a for loop just because he thought it is the only way that he could print them in output using a space separator. I didn't understand the second part... `value+1` ? pointer? what is pointer?

Comment: Please give me a solution with your approach for printing every value in a list incremented by 1. So for `lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]` output `[2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Comment: @ValentinPopescu Is that what OP asked ? Was he trying to do any manipulation to the items in the for loop ? This is totally different question.